# Video not work in mobile

Tags: html, video

I'm working on this site using canvas video with MediaElement.js library. It works fine in desktop browsers but not displaying anything in mobile (android chrome 56).

The weird thing is that when I remove mp4 and ogg source, only use 'webm', at first it still not displaying anything but when I turn my device upside down it works?(maybe need to resize the screen to trigger it?) the videos displaying. So I want to ask:

1/ Incase I have to use 'webm', is there anyway I can tell my web that only use 'webm' type when in tablet & mobile without removing mp4 & ogg source?

2/ do you have any idea how to fix it?

I have tried add muted attr and use absolute urls but still not working.

```
<video id="myVideo" loop="loop" controls="controls" width="300" height="150" muted>
    <source src="/wp-content/uploads/videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="/wp-content/uploads/videos/video.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="/wp-content/uploads/videos/video.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
</video>


    $(video).bind("loadedmetadata", function () {
        video.play();
    });

    $(video).mediaelementplayer({
        success: function (mediaElement, originalNode) {
        }
    });
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: You obviously need a new phone.....:)

Comment: Can you share video link - makes it much easier to help you if you are able to?